# Common usages of views and editors in Eclipse RCP applications regarding to enterprise automation?

Tags: user-interface, eclipse-rcp

I am a software developer working with different ERPs based on different platforms. Java is one of them. I've decided to learn Eclipse RCP. I am trying to understand the basics of Eclipse RCP regarding its views and editors concept.
Working with other platforms I don't care how to make a form in GUI. All the forms in my application can show data say from a DB or save this data back into the DB. And I don't care if a form shows the list of entities or a detailed info about an entity.
Here, in Eclipse RCP, I see that a form can reside in a view or in an editor. What is the difference between them? I would like to hear these differences from a business point of view, please. Or maybe these differences can be explained only in terms like "editor cannot have its own toolbar"? I would like to understand the purposes or common usages as a user not as a developer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki has a goof [FAQ on this topic](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_difference_between_a_view_and_an_editor%3F)

> - There is generally only one instance of a given view per workbench page, but there can be several instances of the same type of editor.
> - Editors can appear in only one region of the page, whereas views can be moved to any part of the page and minimized as fast views.
> - Editors can be in a dirty state, meaning that their contents are unsaved and will be lost if the editor is closed without saving.
> - Views have a local toolbar, whereas editors contribute buttons to the global toolbar.
> - Editors can be associated with a file name or an extension, and this association can be changed by users.

Some advanced use are mentioned

- [here](http://pookzilla.net/wp/2006/10/reusing-editors/), about the ability to reuse an editor for several types of file.
- [or there](http://pookzilla.net/wp/2006/10/link-to-editor/), for linking to an editor

Views can have a different organization than editor: see [fast view](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/09/15/fastview-eclipse-rcp/).

Answer (score 0):

In broad terms:

- Use editors for the main editable "documents".

  - Document lifecycle (open/dirty/save/close) fits neatly with editors.
  - Use all sorts of rich controls, hyperlinks, etc.  It doesn't have to be a text editor.
- Use views to provide optional supplementary analysis/manipulation of the document in the current editor.
- Use views for other (often cross-document) navigation, analysis, search results, etc.